# <f:link.action is not rendering as link when upgraded from typo3 7 to 8

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

```
<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{employee : name}"> {employeeInfo.name}</f:link.action>
```

I want to get details of an employee when clicked on the employee name.

This has been working perfectly in the typo3 v7, But when upgraded to typo3 v8 this is not rendering as link, it is showing as text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere else - I *guess* how you integrate your code into the *templates*. I *guess* you are using something like `page.10.variables.content < styles.content.get`.
Better use

```
lib.content < styles.content.get
```

and in the template

```
<div class="main-menu">
  <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.mainMenu />
</div>
```

See also [what is the best usage of typoscript in fluid templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410877/what-is-the-best-usage-of-typoscript-in-fluid-templates/41422148#41422148)

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible it was a big extension with so many links like this, i need to change it entirely. is there any other option?

Comment: without knowing anything how you do it currently it is kind of impossible to give correct answers

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to typo3. I have done this in typo3 v7 by referencing the typo3 guide, I thought it will work in typo3 v8 also.