# TYPO3 Fluid: Only SOME HTML tags are not rendered in fluid template

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I've a very strange behavior and a question for TYPO3 experts: Some HTML tags are not rendered, the output is like: `&lt;form enctype=&quot;multipart/form-data&quot; /&gt;`

But only with the tags `<form>, <input>, <label>, <figure>`

All the other tags `<div>, <p>, <span>, <button>, <h2>, even <script>` are working perfectly.

Btw. it has nothing to do with `<f:format.html> or <f:format.raw>` because I don’t have an output from the system, it’s directly in the template.

Here is my template:

```
<html xmlns:f="https://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="content">

    <f:flashMessages />

    <figure class="test">NOT working - tags rendered as text</figure>
    <form action="">NOT working - tags rendered as text</form>

    <div class="employees">working</div>
    <p class="paragraph">working</p>

</f:section>
```

Another interesting thing is: **The problem also occurs with the official “form” extension from TYPO3 8.7!** Exactly the same problem, the mentioned tags are not rendered as HTML!

*I hope somebody can help me with this problem. I’m getting crazy with this.*

Environment

- TYPO3: 8.7.22
- PHP: 7.2
- Extensions: realURL, DCE, Extensions Builder,
  Grid Elements, VHS Fluid ViewHelpers, Yoast SEO, news

--- update: added TypoScript and layout file ---

**TypoScript my extension (generated by the Extension Builder)**

```
plugin.tx_rmdataschulungen_rmdataschulungen {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:rmdata_schulungen/Resources/Private/Templates/
        templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_rmdataschulungen_rmdataschulungen.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:rmdata_schulungen/Resources/Private/Partials/
        partialRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_rmdataschulungen_rmdataschulungen.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:rmdata_schulungen/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_rmdataschulungen_rmdataschulungen.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = 106{$plugin.tx_rmdataschulungen_rmdataschulungen.persistence.storagePid}
        #recursive = 1
    }
    features {
        #skipDefaultArguments = 1
        ignoreAllEnableFieldsInBe = 0
        requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 1
    }
    mvc {
        #callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1
    }
}
```

**Layout file (generated by the Extension Builder)**

```
<html xmlns:f="https://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
    <div class="tx-rmdata-schulungen">
        <f:render section="content" />
    </div>
</html>
```

**TypoScript (output page content)**

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
   templateName = Default
   templateRootPaths.1 = fileadmin/Resources/Private/Templates/Page
   variables {
     content < styles.content.get
     nav < Navigation 
     searchbox < lib.searchField
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your layout file? If this is in the template of a plugin, can you also add the TypoScript and template you use to add content to the page?

Comment: I added the TypoScript (generated by the Extension Builder) and my layout file (also generated by the Extension Builder)

Comment: I meant the TypoScript used to add the content to your page

Comment: sorry, I added the TypoScript.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. It looks like something parsing the HTML. Try to deinstall all extensions and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the concept of variables for such dynamic content because of not only this issue.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410877/what-is-the-best-usage-of-typoscript-in-fluid-templates/41422148#41422148) and my answer for a detailed feedback

Comment: Hi Georg,
thanks for your answer - you’re right, but technically it should work, right?

The other question is: Why does the same problem occur with the official "Form" extension from Typo3? The <form> tag is also written as text and not as HTML.

Comment: problem is because f:format.html does escaping of tags which are not valid for editors and form is part of that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem: The problem was indeed `<f:format.html>` BUT in the main template.

I always edited my extension template -> but with `<f:format.raw>` in my website template (for the general output) everything works fine (although I don’t understand why this special behavior regarding the HTML tags occurs).