# TYPO3 v10 Upgrade Fluid Displays HTML Tags

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x

I recently upgraded from version 9 to 10 and after that, some extensions where I overwrite fluid template renders plain html like that:

```
<center><div id="event-id-{event.uid}-arrow"class="arrow-down"></div></center>
```

TYPOSCRIPT:

```
plugin.tx_sfeventmgt {
  view {
    templateRootPaths {
      0 = {$plugin.tx_sfeventmgt.view.templateRootPath}
      1 = fileadmin/templates/sf_event_mgt/Templates/
    }
    partialRootPaths {
      0 = {$plugin.tx_sfeventmgt.view.partialRootPath}
      1 = fileadmin/templates/sf_event_mgt/Partials/
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
      0 = {$plugin.tx_sfeventmgt.view.layoutRootPath}
      1 = fileadmin/templates/sf_event_mgt/Layouts/
    }
  }
}
```

Partials/Event/ListItem.html:

```
<div style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: -0.75rem; margin-right: -0.75rem; " onclick="" class="list-view-item hoverbackground">
    <center><div id="event-id-{event.uid}-arrow"class="arrow-down"></div></center>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Any hints why this happens on version 10 and not on version 9?

Regards

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That Fluid does not replace {event.uid} with the expected record uid from the database or that surrounding <div> from your partial is missing? 

I tested your partial snippet with the extension and this renders as expected with the latest TYPO3 10.4 core version.

Comment: Hi @derhansen, I juste made a screenshot: https://pasteimg.com/image/image.fVcjU

Comment: So I found a little bit more... Also Typo3 Forms are not working anymore. I have exactly same problem described here, but I have no Idea how to fix it and why it happens now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864481/typo3-fluid-only-some-html-tags-are-not-rendered-in-fluid-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem will most likely be, that you must remove the `<f:format.html>` viewHelper somewhere in your template or layout file(s).

I recommend that you remove `<f:format.html>` in your template files (templates, layouts and partials) step by step in order to identify, where the ViewHelper is used "wrong".

**Background:**

With the security fix [TYPO3-CORE-SA-2021-013](https://typo3.org/security/advisory/typo3-core-sa-2021-013) the HTML sanitizer component has been introduced to TYPO3 core. This component ensures, that potentially malicious markup will be escaped when content is rendered through the `<f:format.html>` ViewHelper. This ViewHelper should usually be used to render content from rich text fields. If you use this ViewHelper to render plain HTML, then you will experience the described problems, since the HTML sanitizer will simply escape markup that is not allowed.

Example:

```
<f:format.html>
    <style>p {font-size: 10px;}</style>

    <center>Text is centered</center>

    <strong>Text is bold</strong>

    <f:link.external uri="https://typo3.org">https://typo3.org</f:link.external>
</f:format.html>
```

This will render the following HTML:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>    &lt;style&gt;p {font-size: 10px;}&lt;/style&gt;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>    </p>&lt;center&gt;Text is centered&lt;/center&gt;
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>    <strong>Text is bold</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>    <a href="https://typo3.org" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">https://typo3.org</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

You see, that both the `<style>` and the `<center>` tags are escaped when rendered (similar to the scenario in your screenshot).

**Note:** Please do not simply replace the `<f:format.html>` viewHelper with `<f:format.raw>`, since this may introduce a cross-site scripting security vulnerability when the ViewHelper is used with untrusted user input.

Also please do not disable HTML sanitizer by in frontend context by setting `[SYS][features][security.frontend.htmlSanitizeParseFuncDefault] = false` in install tool.

Comment: Yes I just tested it with a v9 containing this change and it also appears here... so this is definitively the problem, but to be honest I searched whole template folder for use of format.html and no hit here. I tried to disable it with typoscript by    stdWrap.parseFunc {
    htmlSanitize = 0
  }   
} but still no luck, any other idea how to debug it and find the path?

Comment: It is possible to disable the HTML sanitation globally using `lib.parseFunc.htmlSanitize = 0` and `lib.parseFunc_RTE.htmlSanitize = 0` but that is really not recommended. If no `<f:format.html>` ViewHelper is used in the template, I suggest to disable all extensions and reduce the TypoScript template to a minimum first, and then to re-enable every line/part of the template step by step.

Comment: Thanks, did the disable command. Also this one is not working. I enabled debugging mode to log out who calls this and I got this `Fri, 21 Jan 2022 23:33:32 +0100 [DEBUG] request="6d2ef5105571c" component="TYPO3.HtmlSanitizer.Visitor.CommonVisitor": Found unexpected tag {nodeName} - {"behavior":"default","nodeName":"form","initiator":""}` So actually nothing is the initiator.... or how to interpret that?

Comment: I actually found the solution, there is a feature toggle in the INSTALL TOOL always enabling this sanitization. For Disabling it I needed to switch it there off (which is quite uncool as it is a security Feature I know but to be honest I have no other chance as it does not work like it should).... If you want to include it maybe as hint in you answer, I can mark it as correct answer... surely this helps other people having trouble

Comment: I updated the answer. However, I really recommend to re-enable the HTML sanitizer and to find the problem. The previous error message you posted already gives a hint, what could be wrong. It states, that it found an unexpected <form>-tag, so I recommend to check your template for any <form>-tags and check the markup in that area for possible errors.